# Python - Stacking two histograms with a scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Having an example code for a scatter plot along with their histograms

```
x = np.random.rand(5000,1)
y = np.random.rand(5000,1)



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y, facecolors='none')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)



fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.hist(x, bins=25, fill = None, facecolor='none', 
        edgecolor='black', linewidth = 1)



fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.hist(y, bins=25 , fill = None, facecolor='none', 
        edgecolor='black', linewidth = 1)
```

What I'm wanting to do is to create this graph with the histograms attached to their respected axis almost like this example

[image]

I'm familiar with stacking and merging the x-axis

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3)
ax1.scatter(x, y)
ax2.hist(x, bins=25, fill = None, facecolor='none', 
        edgecolor='black', linewidth = 1)
ax3.hist(y, bins=25 , fill = None, facecolor='none', 
        edgecolor='black', linewidth = 1)

f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
```

[image]

But I have no idea how to attach the histograms to the y axis and x axis like in the picture I posted above, and on top of that, how to vary the size of the graphs (ie make the scatter plot larger and the histograms smaller in comparison)

Answer (score 6):

Seaborn is the way to go for quick statistical plots. But if you want to avoid another dependency you can use [`subplot2grid`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) to place the subplots and the keywords `sharex` and `sharey` to make sure the axes are synchronized.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

scatter_axes = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
x_hist_axes = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0), colspan=2,
                               sharex=scatter_axes)
y_hist_axes = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 2), rowspan=2,
                               sharey=scatter_axes)

scatter_axes.plot(x, y, '.')
x_hist_axes.hist(x)
y_hist_axes.hist(y, orientation='horizontal')
```

[image: plot]

You should always look at the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) before asking how to plot something, chances are that it will save you a few keystrokes -- I mean you won't have to ask. There are actually two plots like this in the gallery. Unfortunately the code is old and does not take advantage of `subplot2grid`, [the first one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html) uses rectangles and the [second one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/scatter_hist.html) uses `axes_grid`, which is a somewhat weird beast. That's why I posted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's hard to do this solely with `matplotlib` but you can use `seaborn` which has `jointplot` function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

x = np.random.rand(1000,1)
y = np.random.rand(1000,1)
data = np.column_stack((x,y))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["x", "y"])

sns.jointplot(x="x", y="y", data=df);
```

[image]